How to optimize checkbox selection logic and minimize loops in React?
I'm working on a React project where I have multiple lists of items with checkboxes, similar to the checkbox selection feature in the shopping cart page of Shopee. Currently, I've implemented the checkbox functionality using React state and handling events for individual checkboxes and select-all checkbox.
However, I'm concerned about the performance implications, especially when dealing with a large number of lists or items. I noticed that my code involves multiple loops and wondering if there's a better way to optimize the selection logic and minimize the use of loops.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const lists = [
    { name: 'list1', items: ['a', 'b', 'c'] },
    { name: 'list2', items: ['x', 'y', 'z'] },
    { name: 'list3', items: ['1', '2', '3'] },
  ];

  const [selectedLists, setSelectedLists] = useState(() => {
    const initialSelectedLists = {};
    lists.forEach((list) => {
      initialSelectedLists[list.name] = [];
    });
    return initialSelectedLists;
  });

  const handleListCheckboxChange = (listName, listItems) => {
    const newListState = { ...selectedLists };
    const currentList = newListState[listName];
    newListState[listName] = currentList.length === listItems.length ? [] : [...listItems];
    setSelectedLists(newListState);
  };

  const handleAllListsCheckboxChange = () => {
    const newListState = {};
    const anyListUnselected = lists.some((list) => {
      const { name, items } = list;
      return selectedLists[name].length !== items.length;
    });

    lists.forEach((list) => {
      const { name, items } = list;
      newListState[name] = anyListUnselected ? [...items] : [];
    });

    setSelectedLists(newListState);
  };

  const handleListItemCheckboxChange = (listName, item) => {
    const newListState = { ...selectedLists };
    const currentList = newListState[listName];
    const itemIndex = currentList.indexOf(item);

    if (itemIndex !== -1) {
      newListState[listName] = [
        ...currentList.slice(0, itemIndex),
        ...currentList.slice(itemIndex + 1),
      ];
    } else {
      newListState[listName] = [...currentList, item];
    }

    setSelectedLists(newListState);
  };

  const allItemsSelected = (listName) => {
    const list = getListByName(listName);
    return selectedLists[listName].length === list.items.length;
  };

  const allListsSelected = () => {
    return lists.every((list) =>
      allItemsSelected(list.name)
    );
  };

  const getListByName = (listName) => {
    return lists.find((list) => list.name === listName);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleAllListsCheckboxChange}>
        {allListsSelected() ? 'Unselect All' : 'Select All'}
      </button>
      {lists.map((list) => (
        <div key={list.name}>
          <button onClick={() => handleListCheckboxChange(list.name, list.items)}>
            {allItemsSelected(list.name) ? `Unselect ${list.name}` : `Select ${list.name}`}
          </button>
          {list.items.map((item) => (
            <div key={item}>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={selectedLists[list.name].includes(item)}
                onChange={() => handleListItemCheckboxChange(list.name, item)}
              />
              {item}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

code: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/romantic-borg-qhngwq
I'd appreciate any suggestions or best practices to improve the performance and efficiency of the checkbox functionality, similar to how it's implemented in Shopee's shopping cart page
I want to reduce the loop overhead, and I'm looking for an optimal way to do it, but I'm not sure how.

you can change your code like this:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const lists = [
    { name: 'list1', items: ['a', 'b', 'c'] },
    { name: 'list2', items: ['x', 'y', 'z'] },
    { name: 'list3', items: ['1', '2', '3'] },
  ];

  const initialSelectedLists = lists.reduce((acc, list) => {
    acc[list.name] = list.items.reduce((itemAcc, item) => {
      itemAcc[item] = false;
      return itemAcc;
    }, {});
    return acc;
  }, {});

  const [selectedLists, setSelectedLists] = useState(initialSelectedLists);

  const toggleListSelection = (listName) => {
    setSelectedLists(prevState => {
      const newListState = { ...prevState };
      const allSelected = Object.values(newListState[listName]).every(value => value);
      newListState[listName] = Object.fromEntries(lists.find(list => list.name === listName).items.map(item => [item, !allSelected]));
      return newListState;
    });
  };

  const toggleAllListsSelection = () => {
    setSelectedLists(prevState => {
      const newListState = {};
      const anyListUnselected = lists.some(list => {
        const { name, items } = list;
        return Object.values(prevState[name]).some(value => !value);
      });
      lists.forEach(list => {
        const { name, items } = list;
        newListState[name] = anyListUnselected ? Object.fromEntries(items.map(item => [item, true])) : {};
      });
      return newListState;
    });
  };

  const toggleItemSelection = (listName, item) => {
    setSelectedLists(prevState => {
      const newListState = { ...prevState };
      newListState[listName][item] = !newListState[listName][item];
      return newListState;
    });
  };

  const allItemsSelected = (listName) => {
    return Object.values(selectedLists[listName]).every(value => value);
  };

  const allListsSelected = () => {
    return lists.every(list => allItemsSelected(list.name));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleAllListsSelection}>
        {allListsSelected() ? 'Unselect All' : 'Select All'}
      </button>
      {lists.map(list => (
        <div key={list.name}>
          <button onClick={() => toggleListSelection(list.name)}>
            {allItemsSelected(list.name) ? `Unselect ${list.name}` : `Select ${list.name}`}
          </button>
          {list.items.map(item => (
            <div key={item}>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={selectedLists[list.name][item]}
                onChange={() => toggleItemSelection(list.name, item)}
              />
              {item}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

this avoids unnecessary state updates, currently, whenever there's a change in selection, the entire state object selectedLists is updated.
Also, rather than using arrays to keep track of selected items in each list, you can use objects where the keys represent the item names and the values represent whether the item is selected or not. Some event handlers are also refactored.
